# Foundation Semigroups Examples

Tags: harmonic-analysis, semigroups

I recently started looking into the subject of foundation semi-groups and I'm trying to find simple (none-trivial) examples of foundations semi-groups.

I know that every locally compact group is foundation and discrete semi-groups are also foundation. Is there another examples?

Thank you

Comment: What is a foundation semigroup?

Answer (score 0):

According to [1], every open subsemigroup of a locally compact group is a foundation semigroup. Moreover, every finite product of foundation semigroups and any image of a foundation semigroup under a continuous and proper homomorphisms is a foundation semigroup.

Another example can be found in [2, Example 2.1].

[1] John W. Baker, Measure algebras on semigroups. The analytical and topological theory of semigroups, 221--252, de Gruyter Exp. Math., 1, de Gruyter, Berlin, 1990.

[2] Henry A. M. Dzinotyiweyi, Gérard L. G. Sleijpen, [A note on measures on foundation semigroups with weakly compact orbits](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~sleij101/Reprints/DSl79.pdf). *Pacific J. Math.* **81** (1979), no. 1, 61--69.